# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from CDSoundEngine _testGetGain all of a sudden?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am at a total loss here..  I have been running my OCUnit tests in the simulator with iOS7 all year long with no problem.  Out of the blue a few days ago, whenever I run my app or run my tests, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS from the line in CocosDenshion.m:

```
ALuint testSourceId = _sources[0].sourceId;
```

What is crazy is that I tried checking out previous commits from long ago that I ran in the simulator just fine, and they also crash on this line now.  I can only build my app or run tests directly on an iOS device.  I have not upgraded anything, and I tried cleaning and even deleting the derived data folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode...

I can't understand why this would all of a sudden be a problem out of the blue.

I see other people having this same problem: http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/exc-bad-access-cdsoundengine-ios7-simulator/11713/2

However, they are claiming that it's something to do with ios7 simulator, which as I said I've been using without a problem all year until just now.

**update**:

The problem apparently is coming from the _initOpenAL method..  When it does:

```
context = alcCreateContext(newDevice, 0);
```

That returns nil....  Why oh why would this suddenly be nil for no reason?

Comment: make certain you have no other processes running with Dhension or even ObjectAL in the simulator (kill the simulator and restart it). I have had some similar 'moments' lately.

Comment: unfortunately that's not it.  I've rebooted...  Cleared the simulator's content & settings...  Its just a bunch of nonsense.

Comment: I installed the 6.1 simulator and it works.. i just cant run it in 7 anymore..  So dumb.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the fact that when I run the app, the console shows:  Denshion::CDAudioManager - Audio session set category AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)"

Comment: I just ran a test, and Dhension works for me with simulator 7.1 and 6.1 , xcode 5.1.1, OSX 10.9.4. Did you upgrade any one of these 2 since the last time it worked for you ?

Comment: no.. I have not upgraded anything, that's what makes no sense..  Literally I could build fine 2 days ago, and then suddenly this nonsense started happening.  Like I said, if I revert back to a commit 2 weeks ago, it still crashes, yet I was building with the 7.0 simulator no problem then.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem. Found that because of the installation a software of the Splashtop Streamer. Splashtop Streamer built open-source software soundflower.

In the System Preferences the Sound Output is Soundflower. You need to change the Internal Speakers（Built-in）.

[image]

Comment: Note that you also have to do the same for the "Input" tab. I had my output set correctly, but I had to change input form Soundflower to "External Microphone" to get a valid context.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly have the same problem when playing sounds in Cocos2d-x 3.6. From code that has not changed since 2011. 
This is a horrible horrible kludge but at least it sort of keeps you going:

stuff in:

```
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return;
#endif
```

So that it the top of the testGetGain(CocosDenshion.m) function looks like:

```
- (void) _testGetGain {
    float testValue = 0.7f;
    #include "TargetConditionals.h"
    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        return;
    #endif
```

This basically will shut down sound on the simulator but at least you can keep testing your other code.

I am not happy with this kludge but at least when you upgrade to a newer cocos2d-x that should fix this the kludge will be wiped away. I suspect that this is entirely a problem within the iOS simulator.